# Black squares showing up in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I’m following a tutorial right now and I have a problem with my final renders.
I’m using open cl with my AMD RX 5700 XT and AMD RYZEN 7 3700X since it faster,

[image]

but the problem that I found out that is whenever I would use both of them black squares show up like this.

[image]

but when I try to use just my cpu or just my gpu to render the black squares don’t show up.

[image]

Anybody know the reason behind this?